# At least more than two cardinality in E/R diagram

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I am making an `E/R diagram` and I have a question. I have **two entities, namely: member and matches.**

To consider something to be a "match", you need at least two members. Now, my problem is: how should I note this? It's not `0.. *`, I assume, because a match is not a match when you have 0 members, right?

It's also not `1.. 1` or `1.. *`, as you can't play it with at least 1 or at most 1....

So, how should I note it? `2.. *` does not exist, but what is the best practice here then?

Comment: Okay, so your suggestion is to put 1.. * on either side?

Comment: What makes you say that _"2..* does not exist"_? This probably depends on the notation used; see e.g. Chen notation here: https://www.smartdraw.com/entity-relationship-diagram/. That being said, when it comes to RDBMS, you'll soon discover that you cannot model a 2..* cardinality using the usual constraint types (NULL / NOT NULL and FOREIGN KEY. And that's probably why e.g. Crow Foot notation doesn't cater for cardinalities such as 2..*.

Comment: Well, I have never seen 2.. * being used, but you mean it DOES exist then? Can I use it without getting a penalty?

Comment: @Siyah: An RDBMS might not be able to enforce such a cardinality using the constraints it offers, but nothing stops you from adding additional business / logical rules on top of the lower-level constraints of your RDBMS in your application(s). That is, the programs that feed / modify the DB can add additional logical constraints on the database entries.

Comment: Got it! I thought it was not possible and all "standard", but it seems like that's not the case. Thank you!

Comment: In many sport matches there is a 'home' side and an 'away' side.  If you are modelling something like this then two `1..*` relationships is a better approach than one `2..*` (not sure that's right anyway).  But, as you've been told, in an ER diagram you can draw what you like.

Comment: the match table would have player_1 and player_2 columns - each with not null constraints and a 1-1 mapping to the player table